# Quectel M95 HTTP POST timeout error

Tags: post, iot

I'm trying to send a POST to a server but I always get the +CME ERROR: 3821. I know that this means "HTTP to read timeout". Then, I tried to change the server to another one, just to test, and then I get the same error 3821. My AT commands list is:

```
AT+CGATT=1
AT+QIFGCNT=0
AT+QICSGP=1,"zap.vivo.com.br"
AT+QIACT
AT+QILOCIP   (IP OK!)

AT+QHTTPURL=38,30
   CONNECT
      http://www.posttestserver.com/post.php
   OK

AT+QHTTPPOST=10,50,80
   CONNECT
      helloworld
   OK
      +CME ERROR: 3821
```

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using directly

```
AT+QHTTPPOST=10,50
```

and not

```
AT+QHTTPPOST=10,50,10
```

Comment: sorry just sloved it by using directly AT+QHTTPPOST=10,50 and not AT+QHTTPPOST=10,50,10 thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem but on get request. My post is ok but when I send any httpget I get error 3821.

Comment: Hi, the 3821 Error means Timeout, that means your Modem is always waiting for more data. you need to change the "x" to a lower value in this command : AT+QHTTPURL=X,30

Answer (score 0):

hello even the issue is one year old i am writing answer if any one needs. In the source file of "ril_http.c" of Quectel modules, add delay of minimum 10ms in HTTP call back handler. it will solve the timeout error and will able to post it successfully.